# How can I see which columns I tried to select when "undefined columns selected"?

Tags: r, dataframe, try-catch

I'm building a package that interfaces with a git repository and works with historical versions of R functions. The trouble is that sometimes, these old functions are expecting the input data.frame to have columns it doesn't have. These columns don't affect the functionality, but they used to be in the data and they were hard-coded in these old functions. So of course, I'm getting an "undefined columns selected" error.

I want to use `tryCatch` to see which columns are missing and add them as dummies to my data.frame. For example,

```
old_fn <- function(x) {
  print(x[, "c"])
  return(x)
}

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(3,4,5))
result <- 0
while(result == 0) {
  result <- tryCatch(
    old_fn(df),
    error = function(cond) {
      if (grepl("undefined columns selected", cond, fixed = T)) {
        missing_cols <- # ????
        for (col in missing_cols) {
          df[[eval(col)]] <- NA
        }
        return(0)
      } else {
      return(1)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

I've tried calling `traceback()` and grepping the `missing_cols` from there but that doesn't seem to work during runtime the way I'd expect. Is there no way to see *which* columns are undefined?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Well, from the code above, I'd want to see `NA` printed to the console, since that's what a successful run of `old_fn` would do. This is a contrived example, of course. See edits

Comment: Any solution I can think of that would parse an error message would be extremely brittle (more so than the legacy functions you're interfacing with)

Comment: Ah, so you think it might be more sensible to just hard-code the columns on myself as I find them? Like, `for (col in c("whatever", "old", "columns")) { if (! col %in% colnames(fn_data)) { fn_data[[eval)col)]] <- NA }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this,
but I would feel very uncomfortable about doing it in an R package that's meant to be used by others.
I don't know if R's CMD check would flag it.

You can see the default function used to subset data frames by typing `` `[.data.frame` `` in the console.
There you can see the formal arguments and the body.
You would see that the default formals are `function (x, i, j, drop = if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 1)`.
You could then use `trace` to inject an expression that would be evaluated at the start of the function evaluation:

```
create_missing_cols <- function(x, j) {
  missing_cols <- setdiff(j, colnames(x))
  if (length(missing_cols) > 0L) {
    for (column in missing_cols) {
      x[[column]] <- NA
    }
  }
  # return
  x
}

trace(`[.data.frame`, 
      print = FALSE, 
      tracer = quote(x <- create_missing_cols(x, j)))

df <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
df[, c("a", "b", "c")]
  a  b  c
1 1 NA NA
2 2 NA NA

untrace(`[.data.frame`)
```

This assumes that you will be using it only when `j` is a character vector.

EDIT: if you do end up using this,
definitely consider using `` on.exit(untrace(`[.data.frame`)) `` right after the call to `trace`,
so that the function is untraced even if errors occur.

Comment: Oh boy. Yeah, I see your point about not wanting to use it in a package. This would be something that only people within my organization would use, but I agree it's a bit uncomfortable. I'll try it out